# Pulling universal quantifier out of parenthesis makes nonequivalent statement?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Assuming I have the statement ∀x(∀y¬Q(x,y)∨P(x)), can I  pull the universal quantifier ∀y out of the parenthesis? Meaning, is this statement equivalent to ∀x∀y(¬Q(x,y)∨P(x)) ?

An approach I tried so far:

1. ∀x((∃y Q(x,y) ) => P(x)).        (original eq.)
2. ∀x((∀y¬Q(x,y))∨P(x))            (De Morgan's application)
3. ∀x∀y(¬Q(x,y)∨P(x)).              (Working off the assumption that taking out the ∀y is a valid operation).
4. ∀x∀y (Q(x,y) => P(x))         (Going backwards from the ¬P v Q definition of implication)

Statement 4 does not seem to be equivalent to statement 1, which suggests that pulling out the universal quantifier is not acceptable. I would greatly appreciate any confirmation of whether this is the case, and if so, what governs when quantifiers can be brought to the outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: Btw, you can use MathJax to type equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Use dollar signs to enclose equations and backslashes for commands: \forall = $\forall$, \exists = $\exists$, etc. You can use detexify to find the name of a symbol.

Comment: Your step from 1 to 2 is wrong: you replaced the expression inside the brackets by its negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original expression: $\forall x~((\exists y~Q(x,y))\to P(x))$ says "For any $x$ it holds that if some $y$ satisfies $Q(x,y)$, then $P(x)$ is satisfied."

Now either consequent is true for all $x$ or, *whenever it is false*, the antecedent is also false (ie for *that* $x$ *no* $y$ can satisfy $Q(x,y)$). Thus the expression equates to: $\forall x~(\neg P(x)\to\forall y~\neg Q(x,y))$

---

The final expression: $\forall x~\forall y~(Q(x,y)\to P(x))$ says: "For any $x$ and $y$, it holds that if $Q(x,y)$ then $P(x)$."

Now either consequent is true for all $x$ or, *whenever it is false*, the antecedent is also false; moreover false for all $y$ when $P(x)$ is false for some $x$. Thus the expression equates to: $\forall x~\forall y~(\neg P(x)\to \neg Q(x,y))$

---

Therefore the original and final expressions are equivalent.

---

Answer (score 5):

For universal quantifier. In general, if $x$ apear in both $A$ and $B$ we have
$$\exists xA(x)\to \forall xB(x)\Rightarrow\forall x(A(x)\to B(x))\tag{1}$$
$$\forall x(A(x)\to B(x))\not\Rightarrow \exists xA(x)\to \forall xB(x)\tag{2}$$
However, if $x$ not apear in $B$ we have
$$\forall x(A(x)\to B)\Leftrightarrow\exists xA(x)\to \forall x B\tag{3}$$
The statement in question is similar to $(3)$, which is also valid.
$$∀x∀y(Q(x,y)→P(x))\Leftrightarrow∀x(∃y Q(x,y)→P(x))\tag{4}$$
And we can formulate a direct proof for $(4)$ by nature deduction
$$\def\fitch#1#2{\hspace{2ex}\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\forall x\forall y(Q(x,y)\to P(x))}
{\fitch{\boxed{a}}
{\forall y(Q(a,y)\to P(a))\\
\fitch{\exists y~Q(a,y)}
{\fitch{\boxed{b}~Q(a,b)}
{Q(a,b)\to P(a)\\
P(a)}\\
P(a)}\\
\exists y~Q(a,y)\to P(a)}\\
\forall x~(\exists y~Q(x,y)\to P(x))}\\
$$
Hence $\forall x\forall y(Q(x,y)\to P(x))\Rightarrow\forall x~(\exists y~Q(x,y)\to P(x))$. For the another direction we have
$$
\fitch{\forall x(\exists y~Q(x,y)\to P(x))}
{\fitch{\boxed{a}}
{\exists y~Q(a,y)\to P(a)\\
\fitch{\boxed{b}~Q(a,b)}
{\exists y~Q(a,y)\\
P(a)}\\
\forall y~(Q(a,y)\to P(a))}\\
\forall x\forall y~(Q(x,y)\to P(x))}$$
Therefore $\forall x~(\exists y~Q(x,y)\to P(x))\Rightarrow \forall x\forall y(Q(x,y)\to P(x))$. This proves $(4)$.

Answer (score 2):

They're equivalent.

Here is a proof:

[image]

This tree was generated [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(%E2%88%80x(%E2%88%80y%C2%ACQ(x,y)%E2%88%A8P(x)))%E2%86%94(%E2%88%80x%E2%88%80y(%C2%ACQ(x,y)%E2%88%A8P(x)))).